# What is best practice to implement SQS on different environments?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sqs

I have implemented a SQS queue in java spring boot application. To implement in different environments I have following approached.

1. Implement multiple queues for each environment so that queue traffic will be sorted.
2. I pass env variable in the message and if the message received at wrong environment throw exception which I believe will put message again in a queue. This approach is not promising but with the fewer number of messages, I thought for same.

Any other approach than this?

This is one of the link I found which is 2=1 and the half year old. [sharing SQS across multiple environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983557/sharing-sqs-across-multiple-environments)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use multiple queues. Don't do option 2.

Option 2 is likely to either

1. starve your environments by continually receiving and not processing the messages (keeping them invisible for the process that really needs them)
2. end up putting a lot of messages into dead queue (assuming you set this up, which you should).

Queues are free. Messages and data transfer are not. Don't waste the stuff you need to pay for.

Each queue dedicated to particular app/environment means you can tune various queue properties for each app, and don't need to worry about "this isn't the message you're looking for" syndrome.